# AngularJS's $routeProvider templateUrl is always returning 404 using Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ejs

So the issue is that AngularJS's `$routeProvider/ngRoute` is not working as I need it to. I can't get it to display the respective `.html` page on its route. I'm always getting `GET http://localhost:3000/home.html 404 (Not Found)` when I try to load the template in my `index.ejs` page.

I have tried many variations of paths to get the `.html` to load but I haven't been successful. I even created `home.html` for each folder in the app to see if it'll grab anything but nothing worked. `ng-include` doesn't work when injected directly into the html either.

**/app.js** *simplified: original code uses `express.router()`*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var ejs = require('ejs');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
    res.render('index', { page: 'index' });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){ console.log('3k'); });
```

**/views/index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WHY???</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <script src="/vendor/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angularApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/public/angular/angularApp.js**

```
var App = angular.module('App',['ngRoute']);

App.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/index/home.html'
        })
        .when('/team', {
            templateUrl: '/views/index/team.html'
        })
        .when('/faq', {
            templateUrl: '/views/index/faq.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
}]);
```

`home.html, team.html, and faq.html` all have simple lines of code for testing purposes. Example: `<h1> This is home.html </h1>`

**Folder Structure**

```
app.js

public/
|-vendor/
|-angular/
| |-angularApp.js

views/
|-index.ejs
|
|-index/
| |-home.html
| |-faq.html
| |-team.html
```

Comment: It seems to be a Path issue .. You must check the proper path for your views..

Comment: @Ved How do I do that? All I know is that express's static path for views is set to `views`. Other than that, I don't know how to check AngularJS's current search path.

Comment: app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendfile('./path/index.html');
    });
Try using this.

Comment: Can you post your folder structure?

Comment: Are views/ and public/ in the same level as app.js?

Comment: You may need:app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));

Comment: @MosheKarmel Yes they are. I'll fix that mistake.

Comment: @MosheKarmel I tried adding `./` to the paths but nothing changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node/Express is serving everything statically from the "public" folder. You need to set all of your URLs relative to the public directory.Your index folder should be moved into public.

```
app.js

public/
|-vendor/
|-angular/
| |-angularApp.js
|views/
| |-index/
| | |-home.html
| | |-faq.html
| | |-team.html

views/
|-index.ejs
```

This folder structure should work.
Also fix this:

```
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/index/home.html'
    })
```

Comment: OMG I love you. But can you explain why AngularJS is following the Express static directory? This kind of explains why my other app worked.

Comment: The leading "/" in your URLs is referring to the base server. Throughout your application the server is pretending that the public folder is all it sees. The fact that your index.ejs file is rendered is through the res.render method. But as far as angular is concerned only the public folder exists!